# How to check if array is on gpu?

Tags: matlab

How to check if an array is stored on the GPU?

For example:

```
A = gpuArray(1:5);    
if isOnGPU(A)
    % This path should be excuted
end
```

Comment: Try [existsOnGPU](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/existsongpu.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compare](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) the [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) of that array with `'gpuArray'` i.e.

```
if strcmp(class(A), 'gpuArray')
   %whatever you want to execute
end
```

Comment: In this case, this approach is fine, but it's usually better to use `isa(A, 'gpuArray')`